# Possible Binary Search Tree and Binary Tree with the following nodes

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Possible Binary Trees and Binary *SEARCH* tree with 3 nodes A,B,C below .

Is it correct?

[image]

Comment: Dixon, I in-lined your graphic but you may want to add a little more clarity/explanation to your question.

Comment: This is a question/answer website. Screenshots seem to be convenient - but they **exclude** anybody who can't look at pictures (think screen readers). Please consider providing your input in a format that works for **everybody**.

Comment: @Ghost, I'm tempted to make that change but I'm not entirely certain a screen reader blindly echoing all those A, B, C, / and \ characters is going to be much of an improvement over a picture.

Comment: Well, that is certainly a valid point. Maybe we have to invent a screen-reader compatible notion for writing down binary tress first.

Comment: Something like `root a, left b, up, right c, done` (for the balanced one) perhaps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about validating an answer that also has more to do with logic than programming.

Answer (score 1):

Close, it's a good attempt.

However, number 3 is not a valid sorted tree since it has A coming after B (BAC). I think instead you should have chosen the final one on the page

```
A
 \
  C
 /
B
```

There's also the mirror of that one:

```
  C
 /
A
 \
  B
```

In terms of *search* tree, number two is the one you want, since all the others have a differential height greater than one.

Comment: I realized third one is wrong as a search tree does that mean only "3" tree exist and 12 binary tree exist?